# Page has a popup that has some input fileds and button to send request

Tags: typescript, playwright

```
test('Send upload jee', async ({ page, browser }) => {
  await Login(page);
  await page.getByText('Projects', { exact: true }).click();
  await page.locator('[id="\\30 "]').click();
  await page.getByLabel('').nth(1).fill('Project Test');
  await page.getByText('Create', { exact: true }).click();

  const popupPromise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
  page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Send Upload Request' }).click()
  await page.getByLabel('').nth(1).click();
  await page.getByLabel('').nth(1).fill('adfbadfb');
  await page.getByLabel('').nth(1).press('Tab');
  await page.getByLabel('').nth(2).fill('some@mailinator.com');
  page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Send Request' }).click()
  const popup = await popupPromise;
  await popup.waitForLoadState();
});
```

the issue is when popup is opened and clicked on the button to send request error will is shown on
const popupPromise = page.waitForEvent('popup'); line, don.t know how to resolve a promise

Comment: And to confirm, the popup is a native browser one? I.e. it is a new window that opens? Which button opens the popup, is it the `'Send Request'` button?

Comment: Add a screenshot of this popup, and if possible add a link to the website

Comment: "send Upload Request open a popup and action is done but test will noot pass because of an error and it is not native

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the site and the exact error. `page.getByRole` should be awaited. It's also a bit unusual to begin listening for the popup so far in advance. Usually, you do it a line above a click that triggers the popup.